# On Bootstrap3, Why this margin is existing?

Tags: css

I make a divs col-*-* in div col-*-*.

Here's my Code

```
<body style="overflow-y:scroll;">
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 text-center" style="background-color: darkgray; height: 50px;">
            <p style="word-break: break-all"><h6></h6></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 text-center" style="background-color: transparent; height: auto;">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="background-color: #003366; height: 40px;">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="background-color: #447e9b; height: 40px;">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="background-color: #ba2121; height: 40px;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

It has margin like this

[image]

How can i remove that margin?

I thought it's why there is 3 col-*-4 in col-*-8, and 8 is not divided 3 equally.

So i changed 4 col-*-3 in col-*-8. But the same result came out.

Where is that margin come from?

How can i treat those margin?

Comment: I guess the transparent div has a padding.

Comment: @Seblor Why? In bootstrap, there all div class="col-*-*" has padding?

Comment: Let me just check real quick

Comment: I ran your code in jsfiddle, I don't havethe same result as you : https://jsfiddle.net/myqmwt91/

Comment: @Seblor, Thanks for your advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `.col-*` that those 3 `.col-*`'s are nested in has a padding. Generally speaking, you should nest `.col-*` classes inside of `.row`. `.row` creates a negative left/right `margin` that offsets the left/right edge `padding`s on `.col-*` classes.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body style="overflow-y:scroll;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 text-center" style="background-color: darkgray; height: 50px;">
        <p style="word-break: break-all">
          <h6></h6></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 text-center" style="background-color: transparent; height: auto;">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="background-color: #003366; height: 40px;">
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="background-color: #447e9b; height: 40px;">
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="background-color: #ba2121; height: 40px;">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your sincere answer